# How can I sync meeting rooms between Exchange and Google Apps?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, g-suite

At my company we're going to move one division off of Exchange (2010) and into Google Apps. We'll still be in the same building, however, so we need a way to handle reserving meeting rooms. Is there a way to have Google Apps use resource information (both free/busy and actually booking the room) from Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Short your cant. :(

Looking thought the Google Documentation, this is one of the features not available. There may be a 3rd Party add-on that Syncs the entries. However I cant see that there is.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. I haven't been able to find anything either. Looks like Google Calendar Interop will do free/busy for users, but not resources like meeting rooms. (Leaving the question open for a little longer in case some miracle-worker swoops in).

Comment: Try checking here - google now supports calendar interoperability with MS exchange, incl. office 365: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7444958?hl=en&ref_topic=7437779